# How to use make_pair to create pair of id and struct (object)?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to create a pair of id and object like this:

```
 #include <iostream>
  #include <utility>
  #include <functional>

  struct num{

      double x;
      double y;

  };


  int main(){

      auto tmp = std::make_pair(1, {1.0, 2.0});

 }
```

I get error as `error: no matching function for call to 'make_pair(int, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)'`

Is there a proper way to create pair of id and object?

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to guess that `{1.0, 2.0}` should be a `num`?

Comment: What type would you expect to be deduced automatically for `auto tmp`?? Your struct is completely unrelated (not introduced at all).

Comment: @NathanOliver good point :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, This is how you should create your pair:

```
auto tmp = std::make_pair(1, num{1.0, 2.0});
```

Or alternatively (as @StoryTeller mentioned):

```
std::pair<int,num> tmp {1, {1.0, 2.0}};
```

Now, in both cases, the compiler has a clue that `{1.0, 2.0}` is meant to be an initializer for the `num`.

Comment: Personally, if naming the types is already a must, I prefer to shorten the line by simply writing `std::pair<int,num> temp{1, {1.0, 2.0}};`

Comment: Never specify template arguments when using `make_pair`, just use the `pair` constructor in that case

Comment: @Praetorian may I ask why ?

Comment: @solti For one, it's less typing. And then there are cases like this where things won't compile `int i = 1; auto tmp = std::make_pair<int,num>(i, {1.0, 2.0});` because of how `make_pair` is defined. Quoting STL - [Don't help the compiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKtHxKJRwp4)

Comment: @Praetorian Thank you very much for mentioning the video

Comment: @Praetorian thank you for mentioning that because earlier I had encountered exact same problem of not compiling while using make_pair